# How do get LineString to show using Leaflet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding, leaflet

I have pipe model in my database and it has geometry attribute (LineString). I added this to pipes_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @pipes = Pipe.all
  @geojson = Array.new

  @pipes.each do |pipe|

    @geojson<< {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      crs: { type: "name", properties: { name: "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
      features: [
        type: 'Feature', 
        properties: {
          geometry: {
            type: 'LineString',
            coordinates: pipe.get_coordinates
          },
          stroke: "#1087bf"
        } 
     ]}
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @geojson }  # respond with the created JSON object
  end
end
```

This is pipes.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#pipes_map").length>0) {
    var geojson;
    var map = L.map('pipes_map', {
      center: [42.44, 19.26],
      zoom: 16
    });
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      max_zoom: 22
    }).addTo(map);

    L.geoJson(geojson).addTo(map);
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'text',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/pipes.json',
      success: function(data) {
        var myStyle = {
          "color": "#ff7800",
          "weight": 5,
          "opacity": 0.65
        };
        geojson = $.parseJSON(data);
        L.geoJson(geojson).addTo(map);                  
      },
      error : function() {
        alert('Error!');
      }
    })
  }
})
```

But my pipes don't appear on the map. What am I doing wrong? Maybe my pipes.json is poorly formated? Or style is not ok?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yeah, I messed up something in the controller...

Answer (score 0):

This is what the controller should look like:

```
def index
@pipes = Pipe.all
@geojson = Array.new

@pipes.each do |pipe|

  @geojson<< {
    type: 'Feature', 
    properties: {
      :category=> pipe.category.name
    },
    geometry: {
      type: 'LineString',
      coordinates: pipe.get_coordinates
    }
  }
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @geojson }  # respond with the created JSON object
end
```

end

The rest is fine.